# reltation "student" does not exist

Tags: mysql

so i just started learning sql i tried to create a table and show it:

```
    CREATE table student (
          student_id INT,
          esm  varchar(20),
          major varchar(20),
    
         primary key (student_id)
    
     );
         
         
         
         
           select *
           from student;
```

but it said this

```
relation "student" does not exist
```

any help would be much appreciate it

[here is the error i get ]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYpFI.png

Comment: What you've provided [works fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0154c135c47685c85236bd3b8d0a0f79)

Comment: it MIGHT just be that it is compiling the entire set of code (create table AND select) at once and failing because the table does not yet exist.  Execute just the create table so it exists.  THEN execute just the select * to query from

Comment: i tried to create a table first but it said this

Comment: permission denied for schema public LINE 1: ...dcb89c0-dc4e-11ec-b5c1-97f021c8fc3c*/ CREATE table student ( ^